# Why doesn't this pipe command work at this special bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, arguments

That script `test.sh` doesn't work after used pipe command. The result shows nothing. Why?

```
#!/bin/bash

fun=$( echo $1 )
echo "$fun"
```

commands are as follows,

```
$ echo 1 | ./test.sh
```

Comment: There is nothing special about that script...

Comment: Your script doesn't do anything with the piped input: you seem to be confusing a script's *positional parameters* with its *standard streams*

Comment: @steeldriver I think it should output '1'. But it shows nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[steeldriver is correct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170354/why-doesnt-this-pipe-command-work-at-this-special-bash-script#comment281106_170354). What you should do is either:

1. Use a command that reads in the standard input:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   fun=$(cat)
   echo "$fun"
   ```

   Or simply:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   cat
   ```
2. Or, to convert standard input into positional parameters, use [`xargs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xargs.1posix.html):

   ```
   $ echo 1 | xargs ./test.sh
   ```
3. Or, use the script the way it is supposed to be used (as coded):

   ```
   ./test.sh 1
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@"
```

Then run it like this

```
./test.sh 1
```

It will echo `1`, don't make it too complicated. And besides, why not just use `echo`? There is no reason to use this script.

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: The reason why i use this script is that I found that error in another script, so I just try to explain that problem in a simple way.